# what I have to do with this error in android studio

Tags: java, android

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
what I have to do with this error in android studio
**Output:**

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error
none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
s=Windowsversion=25.2.2.0&amp;coreVersion=C%3A\Users\zigorat\.android">Found</a>
                                                                               ^
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
[8652]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\zigorat\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
90f9e0a9&amp;os=Windowsversion=25.2.2.0&amp;coreVersion=qemu2%202.2.0">Found</a>
                                                                               ^
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.2.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
C:\Users\zigorat.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading. none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
```

look this xml white spaces or close tags

Comment: please update your answer properly , add some points to make it relevant otherwise it will be closed.